# can't edit specific xml file in Eclipse

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

[There](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609912/cannot-edit-main-xml-in-eclipse-android-project) [are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716777/problems-with-android-xml-editor-and-eclipse-hard-to-manually-edit-xml) similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716777/problems-with-android-xml-editor-and-eclipse-hard-to-manually-edit-xml), but none address my specific issue.

I'm rather new to Android development and Eclipse but was able to follow the tutorials A OK.

In fact, I'm able to edit **activity_main.xml** from a tutorial, but now, in a test project I'm working on, I can't edit my new **activity_main.xml** (again, different project, same filename).

I created the file by right-clicking on the **layout** folder then selecting NEW > OTHER > Android XML Layout File.  I was able to copy some of the other file so that my file now looks essentially like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    </LinearLayout>
```

When I type, the cursor moves around (looping through the text) but no characters appear on the screen.  Again, in the other XML file I can edit with no problem.

I'm hoping that this is just some newbie problem.

Comment: That's a very odd problem that I've never encountered. I would first try cleaning the project and restart Eclipse (which I assume you have tried)

Comment: @codeMagic, actually I didn't thnink to clean the project or restart but after installing Papyrus Eclipse restarted on its own, fixing the problem.  It's a strange one.  If I have time I'll try to replicate for the devs, otherwise I'll just pay attention.

Comment: @codeMagic, feel free to rephrase as a question so that I can accept your answer.

Comment: Are you using the newest ADT *and* the newest Eclipse?  Odd problems have cropped up with text editing in older ADTs.

Comment: @arigold I have posted as an answer. If there's any details that I left out which might be helpful, feel free to add them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had similar problems, though not this exact problem. Sometimes simply restarting Eclipse, or whatever editor you use, can help. Occasionally, Eclipse will not detect changes in your xml  so you need to clean and rebuild the project. You can do this by

> Winodow --> Project --> Clean...

and choose your project

I know there was an issue that I had which was similar with the editor jumping/replacing lines and such which I believe was fixed in a newer version of Eclipse. If I can find a source later I will edit

Answer (score 0):

1. Clear all of text in layout `activity_main.xml` *(in code view)*
2. Drag and drop new `LinearLayout` in layout *(in graphical view)*
3. Go to `Project -> Clean`